# How can 2 knights kill 2 wizards quickly and efficiently?

Tags: magic, armors

A scenario: A powerful wizard (Ghuvj) and an experienced mage (Morritiw) threaten to face off against the non-magical king (Rajerq) and his most loyal knight (Hardh). The 4 will be battling to the death: wizards against regulars.

Ghuvj can:

- Use telekinesis on non-living objects.
- Fire fireballs(every minute) and make small tornadoes (every 10 minutes).
- Create walls of earth once every 4 minutes.

Morritiw can:

- Fire lightning bolts (once every 5 minutes)
- Create a shockwave that knock enemies back (10 mins.)
- Create a sword made of air (7 mins.)

Rajerq and Hardh are deciding their strategy and which weapons to bring.

They will be dueling inside a 40 × 50 ft. room.
What is the best strategy that keeps the king alive?

Comment: You may want to take a look at how other questions on this site are formed.  You've got several open questions, all of which are not very good matches for the WorldBuilding.SE format.  Looking at how others phrase the questions may help you better phrase your own.

Comment: This is an extremely plot-centric question. If your story requires an individual to survive, then write the encounter such that the individual survives. The Worldbuilding SE will help with the environment in which a story takes place, but not the story itself.

Comment: Yes, but I am asking HOW he survives, and if he survives(he doesn't need to.)

Comment: You better rewrite your question to fit into worldbuilding.se, because not it is about storytelling and idea generation, which isn't covered here. Good start would be to ask something like, what armour should the knight wear if he encounters such wizards.

Comment: @Frostfyre I agree with Cort Ammon that this is not great for the site format, but it is not plot-centric: it asks about strategy (in a given world I guess?) as opposed to an element of a story.

Comment: Dude, slow down. You're accumulating close and down votes like crazy. You don't want to get a question ban, right? Visit help center and read what's this site about.

Comment: Combat strategies/tactics are very hard to fit into WorldBuilding questions.  It can be done, and there are examples of it, but they're some of the hardest kinds of questions to ask in this form.  What makes them tricky is that you have an arms race of tactics.  The knights are going to have developed strategies to combat the particular approaches of your wizards, and the wizards are going to develop strategies to combat your knights.  These two co-evolve together creating the remarkable amount of diversity in strategy and tactics we see today.

Comment: One great example is in the tactics of the great sailing warships.  Tactically, everyone agreed that being upwind was advantageous because that permitted you to decide when the engagement occurred.  Everyone agreed, except the French. They *preferred* to be downwind, where they could not force an engagement, but if the opponent tried to engage, they could always run away (running away from upwind was harder).  Entire strategies blossomed around how the countries approached things slightly differently.

Comment: Another example that shows up is gun disarm techniques.  Obviously these techniques are *very* dangerous to attempt.  Every school which teaches them first teaches how you must adjust your tactic to fit your opponent (short/tall, near/far, nervous/calm, thief/rapist, etc.)  However, the schools also teach techniques designed to fit their style. a Krav Maga gun disarm is designed to take complete control over the gun and manipulate it until it is owned by you.  A Tai Chi gun disarm gets out of the way and then tries to manipulate the opponent's center until their center is owned by them.

Comment: An approach you may try for any one of your questions is to turn them into a creative writing exercise.  Take one question, like this one, and write up 10 different fights, each with different tactics and strategies.  Try to make each one truly unique.  After 10 of them, reflect on them and see if any of them strike you as particularly interesting to explore further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of those spells alone could win the battle if strong enough, so we must assume reasonable limits.
Typical rumored limitations on telekinesis limit its effectiveness to:

- things that are not held by a living being
- the above AND things that can be yanked away (weapons)

Bring primitive (no arrowheads, etc) bows, arrows and spears made with **freshly cut** plant material. Even common poplar and willow stay alive a LONG time after.
If you're paranoid, do the same with clothes - armor won't be of too much use anyway, except against Morritiw's sword.

Best case: Ghuvj attempts TK on the arrows (or ignores them in favor of offense - weird, but don't be overconfident, king!), Morritiw's shockwave fails to work due to the arrows' aerodynamic profile, both mages die.

Worst case: Ghuvj and Morritiw cooperate and are quick to catch on, a wall of earth saves both from the volley but cuts off their field of view and pins them there.

That's a good start.

Assuming both mages live:

A cautious probing attack is just a waste of soldiers.

An immediate all-out charge (from both sides of the wall, neither lining up (lightning) nor clumping (fireball, shockwave) will likely be a win, though at cost.

Keeping distance provokes ranged fireballs and lightning bolts. What defense could we have against those? A saline-soaked heavy cloth held on dry sticks could fall prey to TK, though, assuming you're not strangled with it, that at least would mean no fireball the next few seconds.

But getting into ranged combat with mages in cover feels like a bad idea anyway, so - charge.

As for protecting the king? maybe not let them know which one IS king? Just an archer giving suppressive fire; have the knight bark orders.

Yes, there are loops upon loops in this plan, but no plan survives contact with the enemy, and we don't know the stats (magnitude, range, damage, AOE) of the spells (could TK be used to push the wall of earth? Could the shockwave send pieces of it flying? How quickly can a different spell be cast?), and we can only assume everything about the environment had already been mentioned (e.g. that it isn't an option for the royal side to go into debt to hire mercenaries, or that we don't need to worry about vulnerability in the hours following the battle) so it's hard to tell the BEST way to proceed.
There is always risk. Turtling the king is a sure loss, so we must hope he isn't engulfed by a one-hit-kill 30" fireball in the first second.

Answer (score 2):

Have the five loyal guards drop their non-living gear, spread out and attack with their bare hands. As it happens, there are five guards and five expendable attacks. Force the mages to expend their attacks to stay alive.

When the guards are expended, the king and knight attack.

Of course that only works for an evil king.

Comment: Very, very good.

Comment: Or a king with very loyal followers who are willing to lay down their lives to deal with these evil wizards.